# How to build FFmpeg executable for commercial use using Windows?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm developing a commercial software and it requires ffmpeg.exe to run properly.

I'm aware of the FFmpeg legal page (https://www.ffmpeg.org/legal.html) and want to **Compile FFmpeg without "--enable-gpl" and without "--enable-nonfree"**. However the compilation guide (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide) seems neglected because some links lead to 404 pages, and some required programs didn't install properly on my PC, crashed in fact.

I tried all the ways to compile but could not succeed. I use Windows 8.1 and I'm not comfortable with minGW, MSYS, MSVC.

How can I compile FFmpeg executable for commercial use, or better, how can I download ffmpeg.exe (compiled for commercial use) without hassle?

Comment: See https://github.com/m-ab-s/media-autobuild_suite

Comment: @Gyan Tried already without success.

Comment: https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win64/static/  Look for the LGPL build, and then double check that it was compiled the way you want, and in a way that complies with what you need.  You're probably best off e-mailing that guy to see if he can be hired to either do custom builds for you, or script it for you.  Building FFmpeg is not an easy thing.

Comment: How did you fail?

Comment: @Gyan Media-autobuild_suite asked too many questions and complained about MSYS after all these questions. Tried again after installing MSYS but it still complained.

Comment: I think i will use https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/static/ffmpeg-4.2.1-win32-static-lgpl.zip and distribute the original 4.2.1 source code.

Comment: @Andrzej That's the easiest solution. Worth making that the answer.